# Django+Ajax+jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I finally got this to work with the primary view returning json data...but now I'm trying to have it execute other views and I can't get it to work!

When i try to call ajax() i get a server500 error from amishbot/update

Code:

My Ajax Script:

```js
function sayHello(data){
    alert(data.message);
}    

function ajax(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/amishbot/update',
        success:func})}

//this is what is called in the html:
onlick="ajax(sayHello);"
```

My view:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        d = { 'message':'HELLO!' }
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(d), mimetype="application/json")

    return render_to_response('amish/index.html')

def update(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        d = {'message':'YALL'}
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(d), mimetype="application/json")

    return render_to_response('amish/index.html')
```

amish/urls.py:

```py
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
urlpatterns = patterns('amish.views',
    (r'^$','home'),
    (r'^update/$', 'update')
)
```

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT }),
    url(r'^', include('amish.urls')),
)
```

Comment: What is the stack trace you're getting in your server log?

Comment: so I turned DEBUG to False to use the built-in email-to-admin stacktrace...and suddenly it works?  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

do you need to include your amishbot urls.py in your root `urls.py` Under the name `amishbot/`

`(r'^amishbot/', include('amish.urls')),`